# Is it possible to pickpocket Ulfric Stormcloak or General Tullius?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to pickpocket everybody in Skyrim and I was wondering if it was possible to pickpocket these wonderful people.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Everyone in Skyrim can be pickpocketed, except for kids.

---

Also worth mentioning there may be a few exceptions, such as characters that are scripted to do a certain movement, such as when someone turns into a werewolf and draws blood into a recipient.